# Help me find scientific getaways!

Tags: study, geek-travel

https://origins.asu.edu/antarctica-adventure-2015

This is a trip I saw, and was interested in, but apparently it's very expensive.

Do you know any other trips/excursions what are scientific and based on learning etc., which would be a bit cheaper than that?

My budget is $5000 and below, and I'm aiming to get some education out of it basically. Maybe something like a trip to Chile to view through telescopes, or to visit some space companies, maybe a visit to CERN etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Very broad!  Special interest tours are both ubiquitous and multi-thematic.  As a guide on a type of those, I can assure you that their target consumer is well minted anyway.  Consider adding content to your question about what's interesting and what sort of budget you are contemplating.

Comment: Did edit it a bit. Better? :)

Comment: You'd be better off working through special interest groups rather than travel organizers (though some, in major cities such as NYC and Toronto do offer such products). For example, my local astronomy club has trips to the Atacama desert in Chile. If you're more interested in politics and culture, look for "study tours". The best will have serious academics along, but some appear to be overpriced junkets where they've convinced some famous talking head to participate. You should be able to do something quite interesting for a $5k budget, but it would be a waste if not truly 'into' the subject.